# Open cv finding convex hull

Tags: c++, opencv

The following code in OpenCV is for me to detect a yellow color ball and draw its convex hull.The code although doesnt give any compilation errors,gives the following error in the output window.
I used the largest area function to avoid smaller unwanted contours.
The error is

Assertion failed <0 <= contourIdx && contourIdx< last> in cv::drawContours ,file C:Buildsmasters..(some path),line 2299****

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
    #include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
    #include<opencv\cvaux.h>
    #include<opencv\cxcore.h>
    #include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>



    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    int main(){


        Mat img, frame, img2, img3;
        double maxarea = 0;
        int lrgctridx; //largest contour index
        VideoCapture cam(0);
        while (true){
            cam.read(frame);
            cvtColor(frame, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
            //thresholding 
            inRange(img, Scalar(0, 143, 86), Scalar(39, 255, 241), img2);



            //finding contours
            vector<vector<Point>> Contours;
            vector<Vec4i> hier;
            //morphological transformations
            erode(img2, img2, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)));
            erode(img2, img2, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(3, 3)));

            dilate(img2, img2, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8, 8)));
            dilate(img2, img2, getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(8, 8)));


            //finding the contours required
            findContours(img2, Contours, hier, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(0, 0));



            //finding the contour of largest area and storing its index
            for (int i = 0; i < Contours.size(); i++)
            {
            double a=contourArea(Contours[i]);
            if (a> maxarea)
            {
                maxarea = a;
             lrgctridx=i;
            }

            }
            //convex hulls
            vector<vector<Point> >hull(Contours.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < Contours.size(); i++)
            {
                convexHull(Contours[i], hull[i], false);
            }
            //REQUIRED contour is detected,then draw a convex hull
            if (maxarea!=0)
           drawContours(frame, hull, lrgctridx, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point());



            imshow("output", frame);
            char key = waitKey(33);
            if (key == 27) break;



        }









    }
```

Any  help would be much appreciated.Thaanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset `lrgctridx` at every iteration.

Say you find a countour at time "t", and you set `lrgctridx = 1;`. At time "t+1" you don't find any contours, so `Contours` and `hull` size will be `0`, but you're trying to access position 1.

Just put `lrgctridx = 0` before the `for` loop. Same for `maxarea`.

```
lrgctridx = 0;
maxarea = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Contours.size(); i++)
{
....
```

Now your condition to draw contours is ok, but you'd better replace it with

```
if(!Contours.empty()) {
    drawContours(...);
    ....
```

Comment: At time =t+1 Suppose there are no contours.The value of lrgctrdx is 0 wouldnt it still draw a contour.if im correct the only thing preventing that is the area!=0 part? If i remove that line the code seems to work fine..i dont understand

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan yeah, you should also reset `maxarea = 0` together with lrgctridx, so you won't call drawContours. Or just `if(!Contours.empty()) { drawContours...`

Comment: Cool..and the code works the same if i remove the area!=0 condition..why is that??

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan I suppose that if  `hull` is empty, you don't draw anything

Comment: Ahh..just as i suspected..great

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan but put a check before that! don't rely on limit cases to always work.